# Vue PWA plugin adjusting iconPaths and manifest destination

Tags: vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3

I have attached 2 screenshots, one of my vue.config.js and another of a section of the unminified output my build is producing.

Whats happening is this: I want to change the icon paths and the path to the manifest. For whatever reason the official way of changing this is not working. Right now they are blank spaces, however it was not working when it was anything else either ( just tried with 'foo/bar' as the path as I was typing this to triple check ).

I am confused because I seem to be doing everything exactly as I should according to the official docs. Is there anything another set of eyes can spot that I am missing?
[image: example of how I am still getting the same default output]

[image: example of my vue.config pwa setup]

Comment: created an issue ticket on the vue cli3 github page : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3149

Comment: Right now I am having an issue with the manifest and icons reading properly. I have manually inserted the correct reference to all of these files within the index page, so Vue cli is copying those references over as I'd like, however it is also generating these extra references with every build. Which I am hypothesizing is conflicting with my own references since the generated ones come last. If I could just tell the cli to not even generate these references that would be great. If I could reliably have it generate the correct references that I want that would work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Greetings ***Erik White***

At some point I had the same difficulty and solved it as follows:

---

1. Copy the images into the **"public"** folder

   - ***example:***
     We add the folder **"favicon"** to **"public"**, **"favicon"** contains 5 images

   ```
   [project]/public/favicon/favicon-32x32.png
   [project]/public/favicon/favicon-16x16.png
   [project]/public/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
   [project]/public/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg
   [project]/public/favicon/msapplication-icon-144x144.png
   ```
2. To add images in your html: modify the **"vue.config.js"** and add.

   ```
   // Inside vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     // ... other vue-cli plugin options ...
     pwa: {
     // ...
       iconPaths: {
         favicon32: 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png',
         favicon16: 'favicon/favicon-16x16.png',
         appleTouchIcon: 'favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png',
         maskIcon: 'favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
         msTileImage: 'favicon/msapplication-icon-144x144.png'
       }
     // ...
     }
   }
   ```
3. To change the path and name of **"manifest.json"** modify the **"vue.config.js"** and add:

   ```
   // Inside vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     // ... other vue-cli plugin options ...
     pwa: {
     // ...
       manifestPath: 'my_new_manifest.json',
     // ...
     }
   }
   ```
4. To change the properties of the **"manifest.json"**, (name, images, color, etc) modify the **"vue.config.js"** and add:

   ```
   // Inside vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     // ... other vue-cli plugin options ...
     pwa: {
       // ...
       manifestOptions: {
         name: 'etc ..',
         short_name: 'etc ..',
         theme_color: '# f44647',
         background_color: '# f44647',
         start_url: 'index.html',
         display: 'standalone',
         orientation: 'portrait',
         icons: [
           {
             src: './favicon/favicon-32x32.png',
             sizes: '32x32',
             type: 'image/png'
           },
           {
             src: './favicon/favicon-16x16.png',
             sizes: '16x16',
             type: 'image/png'
           },
           {
             src: './favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png',
             sizes: '152x152',
             type: 'image/png'
           },
           {
             src: './favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
             sizes: '942x942',
             type: 'image/svg+xml'
           },
           {
             src: './favicon/msapplication-icon-144x144.png',
             sizes: '144x144',
             type: 'image/png'
           },
         ]
       },
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```

---

### NOTE

1. **chucks** is not a supported parameter.
2. **excludeChucks** is not a supported parameter.
3. If you need to test a service worker locally, **build the application** and run a simple HTTP-server from your build directory. It's recommended to use a browser incognito window to avoid complications with your browser cache.
4. Remember to see the **VUE documentation**, it is very detailed, I leave you a link below [@vue/cli-plugin-pwa](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Comment: btw starting from `vue-cli 4.3.0`, if the value of an item in `iconPaths` is `null` it won't be included in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved by updating my dependencies.

guessing this was fixed in a patch i didnt catch